# How to search a string and extract another string pattern from a text file using windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

Consider **out.txt** file has the following format:

```
Display Variable;

    ID    NAME       value
===*==========*================
201  Variavle     07Dec2014

Display Variable12;

ID    NAME          value
===*==========*================
201  Variavle12     08Dec2014

Display Variable123;

ID    NAME       value
===*==========*================
201  Variavle123     09Dec2014
```

In batch file we need to search for **Variable**, **Variable12** and **Variable123** and return each string in column **value** to batch file to environment variables with the names from column **NAME** like

```
SET Variavle=09Dec2014
SET Variavle12=08Dec2014
SET Variavle123=09Dec2014
```

Please help me to get it done.

Comment: Hi John, what have you tried? It could be interesting to see what kind of code are you using and where exactly are you having problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2,3 delims= " %%A in ('FINDSTR /i /r  /c:"Variavle.* " out.txt') do (
    set "%%A=%%B"
)

set Variavle
```

Comment: Following code helped me get the var=value@echo off 
 for /f "tokens=* " %%A in ('FINDSTR /i /r  /c:"Variable     " D:\test.txt') do (    
 SET _test=%%A
 SET Variable=%_test:~20,5%
 ECHO %Variable%
 )

Answer (score 0):

Following code helped me to find the answer

```
SET Variavle=09Dec2014
```

SET Variavle12=08Dec2014
SET Variavle123=09Dec2014

```
@echo off   
for /f "tokens=* " %%A in ('FINDSTR /i /r  /c:"Variable     " D:\test.txt') do (    
SET _test=%%A
SET Variable=%_test:~20,5%
ECHO %Variable%
)
```

...
...

Let me know if any changes !

Thanx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

@npocmaka

```
"dev.bat"
```

@echo off
for /f "tokens=* " %%A in ('FINDSTR /i /r  /c:"nBegin_fcst_dt      " D:\test.txt') do (
    SET _test=Variavle     20142
    SET nBegin_fcst_dt=%_test:~13,5%
    ECHO:%nBegin_fcst_dt%
    )
"D:\test.txt"
    ID    NAME       value
===*==========*================
    201  Variavle     20142

I just ran the above script like "test.bat"

I got some weird output.

Expected output 
20142

when i ran the script, i got the actual output at third time

```
First time: Nothing
```

Second time:~13,5
Third time:20142

D:>dev.bat

D:>dev.bat
~13,5
D:>dev.bat
20142